# PHP OOP & MVC good practice

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I am using PHP and parse, I have had this question for a long time in my mind thinking that I will solve it my self but I couldn't find a good answer for it.

For example this scenario:

I subclassed parse tables to a model so it looks like this:

**Building Class**

```
class Building extends ParseObject {
    public static $parseClassName = "Building";


    public static function getCityBuildings($city = null) {
        $query = new ParseQuery("Building");
        if($city){
            $query->equalTo("city", $city);
        }
        $myBuildings = $query->find();

        if(empty($myBuildings)){
            return new Building();
        }else{
            return $myBuildings;
        }
    }

    public static function removeBuilding($objectId){
        $query = new ParseQuery("Building");
        $Building = $query->get($objectId);
        $Building->destroy();
    }
}
```

Now lets say I have PHP page that needs to show my buildings but because we don't want the user to reload the page everytime he changes the city I need to use AJAX to a PHP page after he changes the combobox.

**index.php**

```
//getting some default values.
$myBuildings: Building::getMyBuildings();

<hmtl combobox with default buildings>
<html combobox with cities>

// Imagine some code in where i can AJAX to a php page and change the combobox based on the changed city combobox. passing the chosen city value.
```

What should I do to connect via AJAX:

1. Go directly into my model class add some checks to POST methods and call the functions. (cant be right)
2. Create a php controller page that calls the model class functions and returns the result to the page. (thats only used for this page requests and so on).
3. Create a class that handles all the connections to the model.

Or, is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Model is a layer mad from multitude of different classes, not a single class. And controllers are only responsible for altering model's state. They are not (or should not be)  gathering data from model layer.

Comment: That class is burning my eyes. :) The public property and the `new` keyword in a method. Needs some Dependency Injection. Anyway, I agree with people who recommend a framework. Since Lavavel is made up of Symfony core components, I suggest learning Symfony from the start.

Comment: @tereško hmm how do you gather data then ?

Comment: The view should be requesting from the model layer what it needs for the rendering. Of course, that requires for you to actually have view instances instead of dump templates.

Answer (score -1):

About the options that you mentioned the second is the more accurate for my understanding. But I will use a framework that already solve this things. So your project will grow safe. And it adds the benefits of cooperating with other people faster, introduce idioms and practices that are tested by the community that use this framework  ... and more

Comment: What framework ? or it doesnt matter...? never used a php framework.

Comment: It doesn't matter. It is your option and your team. I Zend can be overwhelming, maybe symfony or laravel. chose what ever you like the most

Comment: @Raulucco recommending "use a framework" is the worst advice you can give to someone who is trying to understand Separation of Concerns. And most of those "benefits" you listed do not exist.

Comment: @tereško I disagree. The OP is trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @tereško . Those benefits exist and is not me who's saying. Is more productive to discourse problems knowing your environment and haven agree on terms and definitions. Of course is easy to understand separation of concerns using a framework. Frameworks are based on that. Then you can miss use a framework